# How can I get only the first decimal of a number but without rounding it

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I have is : `1.88` or `2.488` and what I want is `1.8` and `2.4`

So basically, I want only the first digit of the decimal but without rounding it.

I tried to use `floor` but it only gives me the number without the decimal. And I found some solutions on Internet but every solution round the number.

Comment: @RoyiNamir that will round the values which is what they don't want.

Comment: What is your column's data type? Doing this correctly for `FLOAT` or `REAL` data is going to depend on rounding, one way or another, because the displayed value is (almost) never the exact value, so slight discrepancies are possible depending on how you're getting the displayed value now. For `DECIMAL` an exact answer is always possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this :

`sELECT  CAST (ROUND(2.488888 , 1, 1) AS decimal(18,1))`

[image]

`sELECT  CAST (ROUND(2.4999999 , 1, 1) AS decimal(18,1))`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use Round() function with third parameter.

ROUND(1.88, 2 ,1)

this function has the following parameters.

ROUND(number, decimals, operation)

- number   Required. The number to be rounded
- decimals Required. The number of decimal places to round number to
- operation    Optional. If 0, it rounds the result to the number of the decimal. If another value than 0, it truncates the result to the number of decimals. The default value is 0

Related link on W3School :- [LINK](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_round.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just a test snippet of various methods for fun and giggles.

> ```
> declare @test table (id int identity(1,1), num decimal(20,3));
> insert into @test (num) values 
>  (1.444)
> ,(1.888)
> ,(123456.111)
> ,(123456.999);
>
> select num
> , convert(decimal(18,1), round(num,1,1)) as unrounded -- best method
> , cast({fn truncate(num, 1)} as decimal(18,1)) as odbc_truncated
> , convert(decimal(18,1), num-num%0.1) as modulusced
> , convert(decimal(18,1), floor(num*10)/10.0) as floored
> , convert(decimal(18,1), round(num-0.05,1)) as rounderood
> , convert(decimal(18,1), stuff(num,charindex('.',num)+2,1,'0')) as stuffed
> , convert(decimal(18,1), left(num,charindex('.',num)+1)) as lefted
> , convert(decimal(18,1), substring(convert(varchar(20),num),1,charindex('.',num)+1)) as substringed
> from @test;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>        num | unrounded | odbc_truncated | modulusced |  floored | rounderood |  stuffed |   lefted | substringed
> ---------: | --------: | -------------: | ---------: | -------: | ---------: | -------: | -------: | ----------:
>      1.444 |       1.4 |            1.4 |        1.4 |      1.4 |        1.4 |      1.4 |      1.4 |         1.4
>      1.888 |       1.8 |            1.8 |        1.8 |      1.8 |        1.8 |      1.8 |      1.8 |         1.8
> 123456.111 |  123456.1 |       123456.1 |   123456.1 | 123456.1 |   123456.1 | 123456.1 | 123456.1 |    123456.1
> 123456.999 |  123456.9 |       123456.9 |   123456.9 | 123456.9 |   123456.9 | 123456.9 | 123456.9 |    123456.9
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fcfd025c6f0c37dfb9f3b2bf0d1e2d9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can tackle this a few different ways. You could convert to character data or do some integer math.

```
declare @Nums table
(
    SomeNumber decimal(7,4)
)

insert @Nums
select 1.88 union all select 2.488

select *
    , left(SomeNumber, charindex('.', convert(varchar(10), SomeNumber)) + 1)
    , convert(decimal(7,1), convert(int, SomeNumber * 10) / 10.0)
from @Nums
```

Answer (score 0):

..[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0aa85e233413c3e636a5a06dd735ec54)..

```
select {fn truncate(val, 1)}
from
(
values(1.88), (2.488)
) as v(val)
```